# CSS - <a href> not clickable

Tags: css, html, href

http://prntscr.com/19fg8x

So I have two divs, one has:

```
.holder { display: table; 
position: fixed;
z-index: 1000;
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
text-align: center;
}
```

And other behind that I have

```
<div>
    <a href="hello.php">Hello hum</a>
</div>
```

But isn't clickable, I can only click it on IE. Well If I remove the height: 100%, it would became clickable, but I need it height 100%..

Any solution?

Comment: Please post a complete code example that we can use to replicate the issue. Also an example on jsFiddle.net is helpful.

Comment: Your `.holder` element is probably covering up the entire page.

Comment: The div is most likely sitting over the link, so you can't click it.

Comment: error: close your last `<a>`

Comment: Yes, I tried to change the z-index to -1 and worked, but I need it 1000, any solution?

Comment: set the `z-index` of the `a` on a higher number than `.holder` wheres the problem?

Comment: I did that, doesn't work :/

Comment: Well, you need a `position` attribute for `z-index` to work on the anchor tag. IE `position:relative`

Comment: @LuisParker: 101 isn't high enough, but maybe 1001 is.  Still though, this is odd.  Can you put your links inside the holder?

Comment: Omg I keep typing wrong.. Yes I DID put <a> z-index: 1001, but that would go in top of my div, if the <a> has many content. I want to make it under my div, but clickable

Comment: First, it would only became clickable if I put the z-index negative for some reason..

Comment: Strangely works in IE, but whatever..

Comment: Why do you need it `position:fixed` anyway? Why not just set the `background-color` of the `body` tag instead? Not sure what you're actually trying to accomplish...

Comment: Because I want to, problem?

Comment: Seems odd, but anyway - I would just do it like this : [http://jsfiddle.net/XKMuS/](http://jsfiddle.net/XKMuS/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set your `.holder` class to your div.

Change your markup to:

```
 <div class="holder">
  <a href="hello.php">Hello hum</a>
 </div>
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jzvN7/2/)

Comment: Noup, can't do that because my div is fixed, so I can't put nothing in top of her, or it would fix in other place

Comment: i mean in your code you put the `<a>` tag before the `.holder`. have a look at the fiddle!

Comment: I tryed, the div goes 10px lower because of the <a> content.

Comment: thats because you did not set the `<a>` on `position: absolute`

Comment: the best way to help you is that you edit your markup, even the `.holder` div is not seen in the question above!

Comment: glad to help you. sometimes the problem is so apperent, no one sees it!

Comment: True, only other question, can I add you in skype? xD

Comment: if you have any other questions ask them on stackoverflow and i will probably see them :)

Answer (score 1):

correct with this:

```
<div>
    <a href="hello.php">Hello hum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Took me a second to see that, closing the a tag should fix the problem :)

Comment: Forgot when writting topic, still problem

Answer (score 0):

Your opening  tag is not closed!

Close it like this:

```
<a href="hello.php">Hello hum</a>
```

**"/"** is important!

Comment: Yes, forgot when I was writting the topic, but same problem

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="hello.php">Hello hum<a>----<--here is error
properly close your <a></a>
```

Comment: Forgot when writting topic, still problem

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<a href="#somthing"></a>

a{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 z-index:1;
 display:block;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```